# How to properly use semantic-ui forms with rails? Form not prepopulating and not saving properly

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, semantic-ui

I am having some trouble trying to adapt a form in Rails to use with semantic-ui.
Is there a proper way to integrate the two?

So far this is what I came up with

**This is the rails form:**

`<%= form.collection_select :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => true } %>`

**This is the semantic-ui form:**

```
<div class="field">
    <label>Category</label>
    <div class="ui fluid selection dropdown multiple search" tabindex="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="product[category_ids][]">
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="default text">Category</div>
        <div class="menu transition hidden" tabindex="-1">
            <% @categories.each do |category| %>
                <option class="item" data-value="<%=category.id%>">
                    <%= category.name %>
                </option>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added the `name="product[category_ids][]"` to the hidden input field and `data-value="<%=category.id%>"` to the options

However, when I save, rails only saves the first category to the database.
Looking into the difference between the two forms, rails parses the rails form as `"category_ids"=>["35", "36", "37"]`
and the Semantic form comes as `"category_ids"=>["35,36,37"]`

I assume the quote marks are the problem here?
How can I fix this?

The other problem I have is that the semntic-ui is not pre-populating the categories that are selected when I try to update.

Any lights on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up fixing it.

I had two problems.
Error saving it to the database, and prepopulating the existent categories.

**#1 Saving it to the database:**

The error: Rails is looking for the hidden input with name="product[category_ids][]"
but the input is returning the ids as one instance inside the array category_ids"=>["35,36,37"] instead of "category_ids"=>["35", "36", "37"].

The solution: Inside the controller `create` and `update` actions, I added a split function to the parameter like this:

```
params[:product][:category_ids] = params[:product][:category_ids][0].split(',')
```

That will change the param from "35,36,37" to "35", "36", "37", and now it will save the selected options to the database.

**#2 pre-populating the existent categories:**

There are two things I had to change, the input value and the HTML links

To repopulate the input value I added this code to the hidden input:

```
 value="<% product.categories.each do |c| %><%= ',' + c.id.to_s %><% end %>">
```

I had to use a multiline block because .each will show the object if you use a one-liner.

To change the Html there is the `option` tag and the `a` tag inside the text field.

To repopulate the `a` tag I used this code:

```
<% product.categories.each do |populated| %>
    <a class="ui label transition visible" data-value="<%= populated.id %>" style="display: inline-block !important;"><%= populated.name %><i class="delete icon"></i></a>
<% end %>
```

To hide the ones that are already selected:

```
        <div class="menu transition hidden" tabindex="-1">
            <% @categories.each do |category| %>
                <option class="item <%= "active filtered" if product.categories.include?(category)%>" data-value="<%= category.id%>" >
                    <%= category.name %>
                </option>
            <% end %>
        </div>
```